# Restful webservice routing

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, .net-4.0

I am working on a .net 4.0 wcf restful service project. As part of the project i have created two services 1) OrderService 2)ProductService

At this moment i have configured them in Global.asax as follows:

```
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("products", new WebServiceHostFactory(),
                                                   typeof (ProductService)));
RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("orders", new WebServiceHostFactory(),
                                                   typeof (OrderService)));
```

I can access the services using following urls:

```
    http://localhost/orders/123
    http://localhost/products/456
```

But my requirement is i must be able to access a particular product in a particular order using the url in the following format:

```
   http://localhost/orders/{orderId}/products/{productId}
```

Can anyone suggest what routing should i use to get the two different services working together.

**Update**: There is method in the ProductService which accepts two parameters

1. orderId and
2. productId

   to return the desired product

Answer (score 0):

In your `OrderService` (and related service contract) expose operation with correct `UriTemplate`

```
public class OrderService : IOrderService
{
    [WebGet(UriTemplate = "{orderId}/products/{productId}")]
    public Product GetOrderProduct(int orderId, int productId)
    {
        ...
    }

}
```

It cannot be in ProductService if it must be accessible throgh `orders` routed to `OrderService`.